# Get a sublist from an ArrayList efficiently

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist, time-complexity

**My Problem**

---

I have a fixed-size ArrayList which contains custom variables. Despite of the ArrayList having a fixed size, sometimes a lot of them will actually be null. The thing is that I need to return the ArrayList without the null variables inside it. ***One important thing to note:*** *the ArrayList will have all of its non-null items first, and then all of the nulls below them, e.g., the elements are not mixed. Example: [non-null, non-null, .... null, null, null]*

**My workaround**

---

I though of creating a for-loop that checked (from last to first index) each of the elements inside the ArrayList to determine if it's null or not. If is null, then I'd call this code:

```
for (i = size-1; i >=0 ; i--) {
    groupList = new ArrayList<>(groupList.subList(0, i));
}
```

**My question**

---

If the ArrayList is too big, this method might me particularly slow (or not?). I was wondering if there exists a better, more performance-friendly solution. AFAIK the .subList method is expensive.

Comment: The `.subList` method is O(1).  It does no copying; it is _super super cheap._

Comment: This shows a serious design problem. What's the point making a list fixed-size and storing nulls inside the list if what you actually want is a variable-size list not containing nulls? Why don't you at least store the index of the first null value in a variable?

Comment: @Rainbolt I was primarily responding to the last sentence of the OP's question, which claimed "the .subList method is expensive."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have a variant of [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm), where your custom comparator is:

- Both elements are null/not null? They are equal
- Only one element is null? The none null is "smaller".

You are looking for the first null element.

This will take O(logn) time, where `n` is the size of the array.

However, taking the sublist of the `ArrayList` that is none null (assuming you are going to copy it to a new list object), is going to be linear time of the elements copied, since you must "touch" each of them.

This gives you total time complexity of `O(logn + k)`, where `k` is number of non null elements, and `n` is the size of the array.

Comment: just changing where the array ends without copying/moving it is O(1)--that should be possible in some languages/with some implementations.  So then O(logn)?

Comment: @brendan Yes, but AFAIK, in java specifically it is going to require to create a custom implementation. Maybe [`ArrayList.removeRange()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#removeRange(int,%20int)) supports that behavior efficiently (probably) but it's a protected method.

Comment: Yup that sounds like java... haha

Answer (score 1):

Following all of your outstanding advices, I modified the original method so that I can take the *last (first) ever null item position* and call the .subList method just once. And here it is:

```
int lastNullIndex = size - 1;

for (i = lastNullIndex; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (null == groupList.get(i)) {
        lastNullIndex = i;
    } else {
        break;
    }
}

groupList = new ArrayList<>(groupList.subList(0, lastNullIndex));
return groupList;
```

If you think it can be further modified so as to allow for a better performance, let us know.